# Heatmap: order y axis based on single x axis variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

In my heatmap I would like to order Species based on percent value (decreasing) in Haul 1. Here is my current code:

> ```
> ggplot(data, aes(Haul, Species)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = Percent)) + 
>   scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") + 
>   labs(fill = "% Sites")+ theme_bw()
> ```

[image]

So the Species order should be b, c, d, a, based on decreasing Percent in Haul 1. I have tried using reorder() but can't find a way to specify the ordering based on Haul 1.

> ```
> ggplot(data, aes(Haul, reorder(Species, Percent))) + geom_tile(aes(fill = Percent)) + 
>   scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") + 
>   labs(fill = "% Sites")+ theme_bw()
> ```

My dataframe is set up like this:

```
Species = rep(c("a","b","c","d"),3)
Haul = rep(c(1,2,3),4)
Percent = c(25,0,25,50,25,0,75,0,50,100,0,50)
data = data.frame(Species, Haul, Percent)
```

Thank you for your help!

Elise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `reorder`, we can use `ifelse` to make other haul values `NA`:

```
ggplot(data, aes(Haul, reorder(Species, ifelse(Haul == 1, Percent, NA), na.rm = TRUE))) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Percent)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") + 
  labs(fill = "% Sites", y = "Species") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! The second technique of making the other hauls NAs worked perfectly. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Yeah, deleting the first one--then second one is strictly better.

Comment: I actually have one more question...say Species A and B have the same % value in Haul 1, but Species A has a higher % in Haul 2 than Species B - is there a way to order Species based on Haul 1 first (as above), followed by Haul 2, then Haul 3 values?

Comment: Not an easy way with `reorder` directly, you probably need to do some data manipulation at that point: `data %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Haul, names_prefix = "Haul", values_from = Percent) %>%
  arrange(across(starts_with("Haul"))) %>%
  pull(Species) -> species_order` then `scale_y_discrete(limits = species_order)`